# How to apply condition on grouped records in a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am looking to find a solution to check multiple conditions within a group. First I'm checking for overlaps between records (based on id) and second I should make an exception for the highest numbered record within the same contagious overlap. On top of that, there can be multiple overlaps for same id.
The example:

```
data = [('A',1000,1,100),
   ('B',1001,0,10),
   ('B',1002,10,15),
   ('B',1002,20,22),
   ('B',1003,25,50),
   ('B',1004,50,55),
   ('B',1005,53,56),
   ('B',1006,60,100),
   ('C',1007,1,100)
 ]

schema = StructType([ \
   StructField("id",StringType(),True), \
   StructField("tran",IntegerType(),True), \
   StructField("start",IntegerType(),True), \
   StructField("end",IntegerType(),True), \
 ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
df.show()

+---+----+-----+---+
| id|tran|start|end|
+---+----+-----+---+
|  A|1000|    1|100|
|  B|1001|    0| 10|
|  B|1002|   10| 15|
|  B|1003|   20| 22|
|  B|1004|   25| 50|
|  B|1005|   50| 55|
|  B|1006|   53| 56|
|  B|1007|   60|100|
|  C|1008|    1|100|
+---+----+-----+---+
```

The desired dataframe should look like this:

```
| id|tran|start|end|valid|
+---+----+-----+---+-----+
|  A|1000|    1|100|  yes| # this is valid because by id there is no overlap between start and end
|  B|1001|    0| 10|   no| # invalid because by id it overlaps with the next
|  B|1002|   10| 15|  yes| # it overlaps with the previous one but it has the highest tran number between the two 
|  B|1003|   20| 22|  yes| # yes because no overlap
|  B|1004|   25| 50|   no| # invalid because overlaps and the tran is not the highest
|  B|1005|   50| 55|   no| # invalid because overlaps and the tran is not the highest
|  B|1006|   53| 56|  yes| # it overlaps with the previous ones but it has the highest tran number among the three contagiously overlapping ones
|  B|1007|   60|100|  yes| # no overlap
|  C|1008|    1|100|  yes| # no overlap
+---+----+-----+---+-----+
```

Massive thanks for the Legend who solves this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join with self, and group by for the dataframe, count how many of the records are overlapped and get the validation.

```
df.alias('a').join(
    df.alias('b'),
    (f.col('a.id') == f.col('b.id')) & (f.col('a.start') != f.col('b.start')) & (f.col('b.start').between(f.col('a.start'), f.col('a.end'))),
    'left'
  ) \
  .groupBy('a.id', 'a.tran', 'a.start', 'a.end') \
  .agg(f.count('b.id').alias('valid')) \
  .withColumn('valid', f.when(f.col('valid') == f.lit(0), 'yes').otherwise('no')) \
  .show()

+---+----+-----+---+-----+
| id|tran|start|end|valid|
+---+----+-----+---+-----+
|  B|1001|    0| 10|   no|
|  A|1000|    1|100|  yes|
|  B|1002|   10| 15|  yes|
|  B|1002|   20| 22|  yes|
|  B|1003|   25| 50|   no|
|  B|1004|   50| 55|   no|
|  B|1005|   53| 56|  yes|
|  B|1006|   60|100|  yes|
|  C|1007|    1|100|  yes|
+---+----+-----+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Import necessary packages

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
```

2. Creating your DataFrame

```
data = [('A',1000,1,100),
        ('B',1001,0,10),
        ('B',1002,10,15),
        ('B',1003,20,22), # The result and dataset mismatched, I have updated it here
        ('B',1004,25,50),
        ('B',1005,50,55),
        ('B',1006,53,56),
        ('B',1007,60,100),
        ('C',1008,1,100)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,"id STRING, tran INT, start INT, end INT")
```

3. Adding some additional columns, that needs for comparing records with the other

```
df = df.withColumn("row_id", row_number().over(Window.orderBy(lit(1))))

df = df.withColumn("lag_tran", lag("tran", 1, "null").over(Window.orderBy("tran")))

df = df.withColumn("lead_id", lead("id", 1, "null").over(Window.orderBy("tran")))

df = df.withColumn("lag_end", lag("end", 1, -1).over(Window.orderBy("tran")))

df = df.withColumn("lead_start", lead("start", 1, -1).over(Window.orderBy("tran")))

df = df.withColumn("valid", lit("no"))
```

4. Let's filter out the records according to your specified conditions

```
# a. Filters out record which doesn't have overlap id
non_id_overlap = df.filter("id != lead_id").withColumn("valid", lit("yes"))

# b. Filters out record which have overlap id
id_overlap = df.filter("id == lead_id")

# c. Filters out record whose start and end doesn't overlap with the next or prev records
non_time_lap = id_overlap.filter("(start > lag_end) and (end < lead_start)").withColumn("valid", lit("yes"))

# d. Filters out record whose start and end doesn't overlap with the next or prev records
time_overlap = id_overlap.filter("(start <= lag_end) or (end >= lead_start)")

# e. Filters out record whose end overlaps with the next start
overlap_next = time_overlap.filter("end >= lead_start")

# f. Filters out record whose start overlaps with the prev end and has the higgest tran
overlap_prev = time_overlap.filter("not(end >= lead_start) and (tran > lag_tran)").withColumn("valid", lit("yes"))
```

5. Let's join all the matched DataFrames together

```
matched_df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), non_id_overlap.schema)

for df in [non_id_overlap,non_time_lap,overlap_next,overlap_prev]:
    matched_df = matched_df.unionByName(df)
```

6. Let's find the non-matched records

```
mismatched_df = df.drop("valid").subtract(matched_df.drop("valid")).withColumn("valid", lit("no"))
```

7. Let's add that together, sort, and remove some columns to get the desired output

```
final_df = matched_df.unionByName(mismatched_df)
final_df = final_df.orderBy("row_id").drop("row_id","lead_id","lag_tran","lag_end","lead_start")
final_df.show()
```

Here it is:

```
+---+----+-----+---+-----+
| id|tran|start|end|valid|
+---+----+-----+---+-----+
|  A|1000|    1|100|  yes|
|  B|1001|    0| 10|   no|
|  B|1002|   10| 15|  yes|
|  B|1003|   20| 22|  yes|
|  B|1004|   25| 50|   no|
|  B|1005|   50| 55|   no|
|  B|1006|   53| 56|  yes|
|  B|1007|   60|100|  yes|
|  C|1008|    1|100|  yes|
+---+----+-----+---+-----+
```